# GCE Ingress error 400 ensureRedirectUrlMap() redirect To Https

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm using GCE ingress, and I need to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTPPS, I added a custom frontend configuration like the following:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: frontendconfig
spec:
  redirectToHttps:
    enabled: true
    responseCodeName: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
```

I used this configuration in the ingress:

```
apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"
kind: "Ingress"
metadata:
  name: "api-ingress"
  namespace: "default"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "STATIC_IP_NAME"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "CERTIFICATE_MANAGER_NAME"
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: "frontendconfig"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: PROJECT_URL
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: "api"
              servicePort: 3000
```

But I see in the ingress logs errors:

```
Error syncing to GCP: error running load balancer syncing routine: loadbalancer lo6kz19c-default-api-ingress-arsturnd does not exist: ensureRedirectUrlMap() = googleapi: Error 400: The url_map resource 'projects/******/global/urlMaps/k8s2-rm-lo6kz19c-default-api-ingress-arsturnd' is already being used by 'projects/******/global/targetHttpProxies/k8s2-tp-lo6kz19c-default-api-ingress-arsturnd', resourceInUseByAnotherResource
```

Updated: Solved
I found the issue, it was a duplicate entry from ingress in another file.

Comment: could you post your  solution as an answer to make it more visible for community if someone would encounter the same issue? What was cause of the issue and your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved, the error was in the code(duplicate code), I was using another ingress in the same deployment but in another file with the same name of the existing ingress.